# Yield return new WaitForSeconds(2) doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

Making simple UI transition between the scenes. When press button "Play" black screen is starting Fade, then waiting 2 second to complete fade and then we load new scene. But LoadScene don't call because script don't go after Yield return new WaitForSeconds(2)

```
private void Awake()
{
    Init();
}

private void Init()
{
    _firstMapButton.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        UIManager.Instance.ShowFadeIn();
        Debug.Log("StartFadeIn");
        StartNewMap();
        Debug.Log("EndOfListener");
    });
}

private void StartNewMap()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartNewMapCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator StartNewMapCoroutine()
{
    Debug.Log("Coroutine has started");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log("SceneLoadDemoScene");
    SceneManager.LoadScene(StaticSceneNames.DEMO_SCENE);
}
```

And there is logs:

- **StartFadeIn**
- **CoroutineHasStarted**
- **EndOfListener**

Comment: If the component was disabled or destroyed, the coroutine won't work.

Comment: @shingo yeah, the problem was that I was deleting everything from the canvas before creating a black screen

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was deleting everything from the canvas before creating a black screen